# unresolvable symbol 'name' referenced in expression

Tags: c, gcc, ld

I have a function defined in a `.c` file (say **funcs.c**):

```
void *funName()
{
    //implementation
}
```

and compiled to a library (`libname.so`).

And I'm compiling another `.c` file (**main.c**) which uses this function, and I'm setting symbol names in command line:

```
gcc -Wl,--just-symbols=symbolsfile.txt main.c -o main -lname
```

**symbolsfile.txt**:

> FunSym = funName;
>   Symbol2 = expression2;
>   ...

but I'm getting this linking error:

> symbolsfile.txt:1: unresolvable symbol 'funName' referenced in expression
>   symbolsfile.txt:2: unresolvable symbol 'expression2' referenced in  expression
>   collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I tried adding a function declaration in **funcs.c** (I don't have a corresponding `.h` file), but it didn't change a thing.

If I change `FunSym = funName` to `FunSym = garbage`, the error changes to "*undefined* symbol...", so I guess the expression `funName` is found.

**Update:**

I tried adding `extern void *funName();` at the top of **main.c** or in a separate header file as suggested in the comments, but it didn't resolve the problem (same error). Is the flag `--just-symbols` needed to be added in compiling `main.c` or in compiling/linking the library (**libname.so**)?

Comment: Have you got an header file with the interface for your shared lib? Is the lib reachable: maybe you must add a `-L` option?

Comment: `-lname.so` --> `-lname`

Comment: @LPs Yes it's a typo in the post (fixed now). I actually write `-lname`. And yes it's reachable. (I have a `-L`)

Comment: Ok: have you provide an header file with, at least, `extern void *funName(void);`

Comment: No. Should I have one?

Comment: @AlaaM. yes, should should have one

Comment: You should have one, or otherwise (not recommended) add the `extern void *funName(void);` at the top of `main.c`.

Comment: @AlaaM. compile with -Wall and you'll get a warning (which is more of an error) about the implicit declaration of `funName` while compiling main.c

Comment: Why do you need `symbolsfile.txt`?

Comment: @Maxim Egorushkin because I have a lot of symbols. The actual situation is more complex that the post... I'm currently trying the solution from the comments but it needs time because the structure is more complicated.

Comment: @LPs I added `extern void *funName(void);` to `main.c` but I'm still getting the same error (also tried a header file). To clarify: `funName()` is a function defined in `libname.so`, the library which `main.c` uses, and I have now `extern [declaration]` in `main.c`. Same result

Comment: How did you create your shared lib?

Comment: @LPs first compiled files to `.o`'s (with `-c` option) and then linked them to `.so` as explained in the post. Did you see **Update 2**? It seems to be working now.

Comment: Please create an answer and move the updates from the question to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the flag `--just-symbols` from compiling `main.c` to linking the library. So compile the library like this:

```
gcc -g -Wl,--just-symbols=symbolsfile.txt -shared -o libname.so *.o
```

and `main.c` like this:

```
gcc main.c -o main -lname
```